# I need a way to mock a printer or spoof it or create a virtual printer where I can see the print

Tags: c#, testing, printing, integration-testing

I need a way to spoof a printer kind of like smtp4dev (http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/).

smtp4dev is a great tool for testing email functionality and I would love to find a product like it that can spoof a printer and provide access to virtual print pages.

Comment: you can install any printer you want and simply point it at a 'file:' port instead of usb/ether/ltp/com

Answer (score 1):

Install a PDF driver and then print to it,  I use [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) for this task.

From a programming point it looks exactly the same as a printer and you have a good preview of what the actual pages would look  like on a printer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have One Note installed, you can print to One Note, which you can then view in One Note.